# Customizing the flow message on the Mobile

Tags: visual-flows, field-service-lightning

We are calling a Flow from the Mobile App and we want to customize the success/error message.

Example. Let us say the Quick Action name is 'Check In'.

Happy Path:
1) From the Mobile App, click on 'Check In', it opens up the flow, enter the checkin, click Finish and the message 'Check In Process Flow completed'.  User Experience is fine.

Error Scneario:
Let us say the record is not eligible for Check In.  In this case, we say that the record is not eligible for Check In.  Click Finish and the message 'Check In Process Flow Completed'.

Now the customer is confused.  Did he/she actually complete the check-in the 2nd time?  Becuase the message is still Check in Process FLow completed.
How do we prevent the misleading 'Flow Completed' message?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check the result from your check-in. Then add a decision based on the result, and show different screens explaining the result. Have these two screens be the finish screens.

Comment: even if I add multiple screens, the end-result is same.  The last screen will say 'Check in Process flow completed'.  Please note that this behavior is only on the Mobile App.  Browser version is good.  I wish I could end the flow with 'Check in Process Flow completed - with errors' or 'Check in Process flow completed successfully'